# Javascript : Capture width / height on overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, overflow

**Here's my problem:**

I've got a wrapper element and a draggable child element within it. 
I need the parent element to expand in size (or atleast get the size data) when overflow occurs. I've used the overflow event but this only triggers at the start / end, not at the resize. I know that i can get the data if i place the getSizeInfo function in the drag / mousemove function but this isn't what i want.

**Code (full version on fiddle):**

```
function getScrollInfo($element){
    var text = 'scrollHeight: ' + $element[0].scrollHeight + '<br/>';
    text += ' Height: ' + $element.height() + '<br/>';
    text += ' scrollTop: ' + $element.scrollTop() + '<br/>';
    info.html(text);

    return{ height:$element[0].scrollHeight}
};

content.on('resize overflow', getScrollInfo(content));
```

**Question:**
I need to get width/ height of an element when overflow + resize occurs (if possible) and also keep the scroll position at the end of the bar.

**Note:**
I know that jQuery can do all this but i've decided to create a custom method for dragging elements because it needed more control over the process.

**FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/f8w8v/2/**

Comment: I never knew there is an event for `overflow`. Thats super useful . Thanks. I wonder why it isn't firing every time the overflow changes though!

Comment: That's exactly what i thought to! I've found that a custom event can be made that triggers when an element is resized but doing this is an extension aswell and that's what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: If it'll be of any help, i've already kind of done the exact thing as a plugin. *Disclaimer: As it must be obvious by now, I've developed it. Suggesting purely so as to save your time redoing it. Not for self promition.. Phew!! SO  and their rules..* - http://techfoobar.com/jquery-style-listener/